# angular 2 relativepath bundle with gulp

Tags: angular, gulp, bundle, relative-path

I am working on a web application using Spring **4.3.5.Release**. I am using angular 2 for front-end. 
Inside components, i used relative paths to the *templateURLs* and *StyleURLs* following the guide here

[Component-relative Paths](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

But i am confused on how to bundle this project structure using gulp as we place all the component related files (*html, css, ts*) etc into the same folder.

I would create a minified version of compiles js files using gulp but how do i maintain this structure for relative path.

Would be really happy if somebody could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gulp-inline-ng2-template](https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template) plugin to inline the CSS and HTML, prior to compiling with `ngc` and bundling with [rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup):

Compiling with `NGC`:

```
gulp.task('compile:aot', function (cb) {
  exec('"node_modules\\.bin\\ngc" -p tsconfig.prod.json', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});
```

Compiling to ES6 module format (pre-requisite for tree-shaking by rollup):

```
gulp.task('compile:es6', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(inlineNg2Template({ base: '/src', useRelativePaths:true }))
    .pipe(tsc({
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/src'));
});
```

Bundle with rollup:

```
gulp.task('rollup:app', function(){
  return rollup.rollup( {
    entry: 'dist/src/main.aot.js',
    onwarn: function (warning) {
      // Skip certain warnings

      // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
      if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') { return; }
      // intercepts in some rollup versions
      if ( warning.message.indexOf("The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'") > -1 ) { return; }

      // console.warn everything else
      console.warn(warning.message);
    },

    plugins: [
          nodeResolve({
            jsnext: true,
            module: true
          }),
          commonjs({
              include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
          })
    ]
  })
  .then(function(bundle) {
      bundle.write( {
        format: "iife",
        dest: "dist/app.bundle.js",
        sourceMap: true
      });
  });
});
```

[Demo Starter App](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-starter-app)

Comment: It worked!! Thank you. I never know there is gulp-inline-ng2-template plugin. Great!!

Comment: One question. As we use NGC, we won't require typescript plugin for compilation, right.

Comment: ngc is used to generate the factories needed for static compilation.  tsc is still required after the factories are created to compile to es6 format prior to bundling and tree-shaking by rollup. You may be able to output to es6 using ngc alone - I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Got confused with both compilers. And thank you very much for the starter app. It would be really helpful for beginners like me.

Comment: sure np:) check out the feature module build which outputs to UMD, AMD, and CJS module formats.  You'll be able to deploy feature modules to NPM and re-use it across multiple applications.

Comment: I tried using AOT, but it throws error on private properties and members of the class. It does it even when i exposed the getters and setters. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Yes, don't declare them private... not ideal, but it works.